# feature file is not running in karate framewrok in intellij

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, karate, web-api-testing, cucumber-junit

I'm new in Karate framework.
And i have create one script which is read the request body from "user.json" file and i have configerd that in feature file. till that it's good but when run feature file, it's giving me an below error:
[image]

json file:
[image]

and i tried to found solution for this but didn't get much result for same.
can anyone please help me out for how to reslove this?

Comment: looks like an issue with your intellij plugin. 2 suggestions, try to get it working with just maven on the command line: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#quickstart - and try the official intellij plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19232-karate

Comment: Please contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and provide the IDE logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data) along with a project sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Plugins : "Gherkin" and "Cucumber for Java" Restart your IDE and you will be able to see the RunAs option when you right click on the file.
Note: Do not install "Cucumber+".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Please install [Karate plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19232-karate) from intellij idea store, it will run perfectly

Comment: I am unable to run the Karate scenario, it's giving me a notification that, I have to take a paid version to run the Karate script